# new grails project won't start

Tags: grails, startup

I'm trying to get my feet wet with grails, so I'm following a tutorial to get going with a sample project. I downloaded grails 2.3.2, added the environment variables for the command prompt commands, and successfully created a project by using >grails create-app teamwork. Calling >grails run-app after changing to the project directory successfully downloads all requisites, but then I get [image: command prompt result]. I know that this exception doesn't reveal much, but do you guys have any ideas on why? I am running command prompt in admin mode, if that means anything.

Comment: did you try to run "grails compile" first ?

Comment: It appears that run app does the compile command (I did try running it before run-app) and I got the same error.

The outputs are:
Environment set to development.....
Running Grails application
then the image above

Comment: Some other things that I just found: in the src folder of the project, there are groovy and java folders, but they're both empty. Also, the lib folder is empty. I was expecting to see some files that grails had created, since it downloaded a bunch of stuff.

Comment: @MichaelDiLeo these are folders of your application, Grails don't add anything in them.

Comment: Witch command exactly are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Try not forking the JVM in **BuildConfig.groovy**, if I recall correctly. If that works, then check the JIRA issues for Grails 2.3.2.